# Does `ios_base::app` guarantee `ios_base::out` is implicitly specified?

Tags: c++, file, io, standards, fstream

A:

`std::ofstream("test.txt", std::ios_base::app);`

B:

`std::ofstream("test.txt", std::ios_base::app|std::ios_base::out);`

Does the C++ standard guarantee A is identical to B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as per [ofstream.cons]

```
explicit basic_ofstream(const char* s,
    ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
```

> Effects: Constructs an object of class basic_ofstream, initializing the base class with `basic_ostream(&sb)` and initializing sb with `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>())`, then calls **`rdbuf()->open(s, mode|ios_base::out)`**. If that function returns a null pointer, `calls setstate(failbit)`.

Note that it isn't `app` that has this guarantee but the call to the underlying streambuf itself; any flags you pass to the constructor/`open` are always ored with `out` (and likewise with `in` for `ifstream`).